# Why is WebMvcConfigurer being loaded?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm new to Spring and testing a Spring Data project with Postgresql/JPA and MongoDB components. My Test class has the following annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMongoConfig.class, PgRepository.class, MongodbRepository.class})
public class PerfTest {

  @Autowired
  private PgRepository pgRepo;

  @Autowired
  private MongodbRepository mongoRep;
```

For some reason the `spring-context` module is trying to load `WebMvcConfigurer` while resolving bean classes, giving me a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Is the Spring Boot Autoconfigure trying to initiate a full web controller suite? If so, why? I'm really just interested in Spring Data. Should I avoid Spring Boot entirely?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't annotate a test class as a `@SpringBootApplication`. This annotation is used to define a class in your main code base which contains a main() method to spin up your Spring boot container with auto-configuration.

If it's Spring data you are interested in testing then your tests will need to point to a `@Configuration` class which is annotated with `@EnableJpaRepositories` this will allow your repository interfaces to be autowired.

I don't know what is in your SpringMongoConfig class but if this contains that annotation then all you need to do is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMongoConfig.class})
public class PerfTest {
```

If not then you need to set up this configuration and include it in the `@ContextConfiguration` of the test.

Another option which is a bit more heavyweight but will guarantee everything is available for your test (provided your Spring boot application is set up correctly) is to mark your test with `@SpringBootTest` this will automatically load the whole Spring boot context for the application. If it has trouble finding your main class you can point it in the right direction by providing the class in the annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyMainClass.class)
public class PerfTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **@Component** to your repository interface. Spring loads the component class first and then @AutoWiring & Initialization of variables will happen.